# Dynamic MySQLi Query String "AND" Appendage

Tags: php, dynamic, mysqli

I have a dynamic query (used for a search function) for my site. It builds the query based on user input, dynamically.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM talents WHERE ";

if(!empty($_POST['firstName'])){
    $query = $query . "firstName = '" . $_POST['firstName'] . "' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST['lastName'])){
    $query = $query . "lastName = '" . $_POST['lastName'] . "' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST['gender'])){
    $query = $query . "gender = '" . $_POST['gender'] . "' AND ";
}


if(!empty($_POST['eyeColor'])){
    $query = $query . "eyeColor = '" . $_POST['eyeColor'] . "' AND ";
}

if($_POST['heightLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['heightHigh'] != "High"){
    $query = $query . "height BETWEEN '" . $_POST['heightLow'] . "' AND '" . $_POST['heightHigh'] . "' AND ";
}else if($_POST['heightLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['heightHigh'] == "High"){
    $query = $query . "height = '" . $_POST['heightLow'] . "' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST['hairColor'])){
    $query = $query . "hairColor = '" . $_POST['hairColor'] . "' AND ";
}

if($_POST['weightLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['weightHigh'] != "High"){
    $query = $query . "weight BETWEEN '" . $_POST['weightLow'] . "' AND '" . $_POST['weightHigh'] . "' AND ";
}else if($_POST['weightLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['weightHigh'] == "High"){
    $query = $query . "weight = '" . $_POST['weightLow'] . "' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST['dressSize'])){
    $query = $query . "dressSize = '" . $_POST['dressSize'] . "' AND ";
}

if($_POST['chestLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['chestHigh'] != "High"){
    $query = $query . "chest BETWEEN '" . $_POST['chestLow'] . "' AND '" . $_POST['chestHigh'] . "' AND ";
}else if($_POST['chestLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['chestHigh'] == "High"){
    $query = $query . "chest = '" . $_POST['chestLow'] . "' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST['shoeSize'])){
    $query = $query . "shoeSize = '" . $_POST['shoeSize'] . "' AND ";
}

if($_POST['waistLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['waistHigh'] != "High"){
    $query = $query . "waist BETWEEN '" . $_POST['waistLow'] . "' AND '" . $_POST['waistHigh'] . "' AND ";
}else if($_POST['waistLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['waistHigh'] == "High"){
    $query = $query . "waist = '" . $_POST['waistLow'] . "' AND ";
}

if($_POST['hipsLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['hipsHigh'] != "High"){
    $query = $query . "hips BETWEEN '" . $_POST['hipsLow'] . "' AND '" . $_POST['hipsHigh'] . "' ";
}else if($_POST['hipsLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['hipsigh'] == "High"){
    $query = $query . "hips = '" . $_POST['hipsLow'] . "' ";
}
```

First off, ignore the verbose nature - it's an alpha to get working. Pretty code after. Second, the `High` and `Low` variables reference a ranged search (e.g. height between 5'3 and 5'9).

Here's my problem; the `AND`! The way I have it, it will work if there is something for the `hips` inputs, other than that it errors out. But then, it's impossible to predict where the user will stop.

This is a really common functionality, I'm surprised this isn't easier to find on the internet. Any quick ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea, sanitize your input. Don't pass $_POST['xxx'] directly in a query.

At the *very least*, wrap it in mysql_real_escape_string(). You're better off, however, using PHP's PDO.

After you escape, it'll start working. You may want to also consider `$query = rtrim($query, "AND")` -- then just continue to put " AND" at the end of your queries.

Example (not tested):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM talents WHERE ";

if(!empty($_POST['firstName'])){
    $query = $query . "firstName = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']) . "' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST['lastName'])){
    $query = $query . "lastName = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']) . "' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST['gender'])){
    $query = $query . "gender = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']) . "' AND ";
}


if(!empty($_POST['eyeColor'])){
    $query = $query . "eyeColor = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eyeColor']) . "' AND ";
}

if($_POST['heightLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['heightHigh'] != "High"){
    $query = $query . "height BETWEEN '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['heightLow']) . "' AND '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['heightHigh']) . "' AND ";
}else if($_POST['heightLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['heightHigh'] == "High"){
    $query = $query . "height = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['heightLow']) . "' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST['hairColor'])){
    $query = $query . "hairColor = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hairColor']) . "' AND ";
}

if($_POST['weightLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['weightHigh'] != "High"){
    $query = $query . "weight BETWEEN '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weightLow']) . "' AND '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weightHigh']) . "' AND ";
}else if($_POST['weightLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['weightHigh'] == "High"){
    $query = $query . "weight = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weightLow']) . "' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST['dressSize'])){
    $query = $query . "dressSize = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dressSize']) . "' AND ";
}

if($_POST['chestLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['chestHigh'] != "High"){
    $query = $query . "chest BETWEEN '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chestLow']) . "' AND '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chestHigh']) . "' AND ";
}else if($_POST['chestLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['chestHigh'] == "High"){
    $query = $query . "chest = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chestLow']) . "' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST['shoeSize'])){
    $query = $query . "shoeSize = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shoeSize']) . "' AND ";
}

if($_POST['waistLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['waistHigh'] != "High"){
    $query = $query . "waist BETWEEN '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['waistLow']) . "' AND '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['waistHigh']) . "' AND ";
}else if($_POST['waistLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['waistHigh'] == "High"){
    $query = $query . "waist = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['waistLow']) . "' AND ";
}

if($_POST['hipsLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['hipsHigh'] != "High"){
    $query = $query . "hips BETWEEN '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hipsLow']) . "' AND '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hipsHigh']) . "' AND";
}else if($_POST['hipsLow'] != "Low" && $_POST['hipsigh'] == "High"){
    $query = $query . "hips = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hipsLow']) . "' AND";
}

$query = rtrim($query, "AND");
```

Comment: Helps to read everything - the `rtrim(...)` did the trick! Quick and easy, I like it.

Comment: I did have a disclaimer to begin with! :|

Answer (score 4):

save your conditions into an `array` instead of `string` like this

```
$query = array();
$query[] = "weight = '" . $_POST['weightLow'];
```

and `implode` it with `AND`.

```
$final_query = implode(' AND ', $query);
```

Comment: Your idea is brilliant, but the `rtrim(...)` was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Christopher you were rather looking for the substr() or this implode() based answer. As rtrim works not the way you think.